# MongoDB4 update nested objects item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i've a problem updating a nested object in MongoDB 4.

I wrote a playground where I'm doing some tests to be able to solve the problem ..

My desiderata is:

1. I need the "email" item to be overwritten with the lowercase of itself (result obtained).
2. I need that in all the N objects contained in the "emailsStatus" array the "emailAddress" item is overwritten with itself but in lowercase

I can not carry out the second point, in the playground you will find everything ready and with the test I am carrying out but I am not succeeding .. What am I wrong?

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJ25souNlYZ

Comment: i would suggest you to add documents and your tried query in your question instead of playground link for the future purpose and better question for future visitors. they will get exact idea after seeing the question instead of redirect to other link.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- Try `$map` to iterate loop of `emailsStatus` array and convert `emailAddress` lower case, merge current object with update email field using `$mergeObjects`,
- one more suggestion for query part is you can check single condition for `email` using `$type` is `string`

```
db.collection.update(
  { email: { $type: "string } },
  [{
    $set: {
      email: { $toLower: "$email" },
      emailsStatus: {
        $map: {
          input: "$emailsStatus",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { emailAddress: { $toLower: "$$this.emailAddress" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dnbozoI4ZX4)

---

Check null condition in `emailAddress` array using `$cond` and `$type`,

```
$map: {
  input: "$emailsStatus",
  in: {
    $mergeObjects: [
      "$$this",
      {
        emailAddress: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.emailAddress" }, "string"] },
            { $toLower: "$$this.emailAddress" },
            "$$this.emailAddress"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AL5uhG3v7cO)